# Material-UI hover effect line offset bug (React)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, jsx

I have been looking to implement Material-UI in my React ES6 project. As I have been trying things in a sandbox, I noticed a pretty significant styling quirk on the RaisedButton component. When hovering at times there is either a line at the top or bottom of the button where the hover effect doesn't completely overlap the button. The behavior changes when I override the margins. For instance when I have 8px margins the plain button has no line. When I add 6px margins the button has a line at the top. When I have a 4px margin it has a line at the bottom. This behavior changes also when there's different components next to each other in the HTML.

I am using Source Sans instead of Roboto, but switching back to Roboto has the same behavior. Likewise, keeping text-transform as uppercase instead of none has the same behavior.

I have tried wrapping the button in a div and applying margin or padding to that with the same result.

I am on the latest Chrome on Mac OSX 10.11.3.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am wrapping the button in a custom class to allow consistent style overrides. Here's my wrappers:

#### Button Wrapper

```
...
let customTheme = ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(CustomTheme)
customTheme.button.textTransform = 'none'
const styles = {
    button: {
        margin: 8
    }
}

@ThemeDecorator(customTheme)
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="c-button" style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                <RaisedButton 
                    style={ styles.button }
                    label={ this.props.label }
                    onClick={ this.props.onClick } 
                    primary={ this.props.primary }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
...
```

#### Modal Wrapper

```
...
render() {
    const actions = [
        <Button
            label="Cancel" 
            onClick={ this.props.handleClose } />,
        <Button
            label="Submit"
            primary={ true }
            onClick={ this.props.handleClose } />
    ]
    return (
        <Dialog
            title="Dialog With Actions"
            actions={ actions }
            open={ this.props.open } >
            Only actions can close this dialog.
        </Dialog>
    )
}
...
```

#### Plain RaisedButton by itself

```
...
<ul>
    <li>
        <h4>Plain Button</h4>
         <Button label="Button" onClick={this.handleClick}/>              
     </li>
</ul>
...
```

#### Plain RaisedButton for Modal

```
...
<li>
    <h4>Plain Modal</h4>
    <Button label="Modal Dialog" onClick={ this.handleOpen } />
    <Modal
        open={ this.state.open }
        handleClose={ this.handleClose }
        handleOpen={ this.handleOpen } />
</li>
...
```

I'm hovering my mouse over the buttons in these screenshots. The only difference is the override of the margin in the first one to be 8px.

[image: button for modal]
[image: button for modal no margin]